# .net MemoryCache usage for data calculation

Tags: .net, caching, c#-4.0, memorycache

I am in need to use some sort of caching in application to calculate timesheet data and cost. I want to cache the calculation so subsequent calls from the UI components to display the values should not recalculate and are performant. I am thinking to use MemoryCache and wondering whether it is right choice to do so. Any pros or cons here for this?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Caching is something to look at if you *know* the values will be expensive to calculate. Offhand, it is hard to envision how calculating timesheet data will be so expensive it will require caching because math is what computers are *really good* at doing. But at the end of the day only *you* will know if caching is the appropriate design choice. Not to mention, the answer may entirely depend on whether this is a thick or thin client application, which is something you didn't specify.

Comment: It is thick client WPF app.